# Trying to export graphics from R (ggplot2) to powerpoint

Tags: reporting, reporters

can someone explain me why the package "ReporteRs" mentioned in numerous communications as THE package to make these kind of export is not anymore available ? What is the replacement ? I read a mention about an alternative : "officer" but I was unable to find it. Many Thanks for your help . Ax

Comment: you can find it on the CRAN page: https://cran.r-project.org/package=officer. Its documentation is here: https://davidgohel.github.io/officer

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to export R graphs to Powerpoint you can also use the wrapper package `export` built on top of `officer` that just came out on CRAN, see
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/export/index.html and for demo
https://github.com/tomwenseleers/export

Typical syntax is very easy, e.g.:

```
install.packages("export")
library(export)
library(ggplot2)
qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data = iris, color = Species, 
      size = Petal.Width, alpha = I(0.7))     
graph2ppt(file="ggplot2_plot.pptx", width=6, height=5)
```

You can also use it to export to Word, Excel, Latex or HTML and you can also use it to export statistical output of various R stats objects.